# CSS to Detect browser and screen resolution

Tags: css

Is there a way to detect browser and screen resolution and adjust wrapper height and display scroll , trying below but not working,

```
    @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
      .wrapper {
        height: 60vh;
        position: relative;
        background-color: white;

         
      }

      @media (resolution: 150dpi) {
        .wrapper {
          height: 55vh;
          position: relative;
          background-color: white;
      
      
           
        
      }
      
        .ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer{
      
          overflow-x:visible;
      
      
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about being able to detect the browser through CSS, might need JS for that.

As for detecting screen width though i'm assuming the screen size is due to desktop/mobile device, if so change

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
```

to

Desktop

```
@media screen and (min-width: desired width) {
```

Mobile

```
@media screen and (max-width: desired width) {
```